# ASP Clásico Dropdown dinámico con SQL

Tags: sql, html5, asp

Etoy trabajando en un sistema para comprobación de gastos, estoy llenado un dropdown como 'Concepto' con datos de una tabla en SQL, y quiero que se llenen otros 2 campos con información de la misma tabla.

Por ejemplo, si selecciono 'Alimentos' tiene un número de cuenta = '1234' y otro como deducible = 'D01', al seleccionar 'Alimentos' quiero que en un textbox muestre su cuenta (1234) y en otro textbox su deducible (D01)

Código:

```
            <%
            qry = "SELECT id_cuenta, concepto, deducible FROM hpx_cuentas where categoria = '5'"
            set rs = con.execute(qry)                                       
            %> 
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="concepto" name="concepto">                        
                    <%while not rs.eof %>
                    <option><%=rs.fields(1)%></option>
                     <%

            rs.movenext
            wend
            %>                    

            <%rs.close
            set rs = nothing                           
            %>
```

¿Tendría que leer el valor seleccionado y hacer otro query? Pero quiero que se haga en automático sin hacer el submit del form que tengo, una vez que muestre esos valores los pondre como ocultos (hidden) ya que es solo información que se guarda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Falta traducir el título de la pregunta

Comment: He cambiado la pregunta, y ahora está todo en español